# NextJS app not returning a response from API

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I have the following API call I am testing in Postman:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to write a NextJS app that will make the same call, but currently, the app is returning null in the console. What am I missing in the app?

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '@components/Header'
import Footer from '@components/Footer'

export default function Home({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ExtBot Logs</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const username = 'user';
  const password = 'password';

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'my_url',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password),
          'URL': 'askhelp',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      }
    );
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Request failed with status ' + response.status);
    }
    
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('API response:', response); // Log the entire response object
    console.log('API data:', data); // Log the extracted data
    return {
      props: {
        data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
        hello: "world",
      }
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('API request error:', err);
    return {
      props: {
        data: null,
        hello: "world",
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be passing a body in the POST request.

Comment: Good catch @juliomalves, thanks! Added a body along with the URL attribute and am not getting a 422 error. I'll keep at it.